# Despite instantiating a variable in my constructor of my Apex class, I'm later told it is null

Tags: apex, visualforce

Assume I have a form (in a VisualForce Page) where I need a user to give me the username and password for a 3rd party system:

```
<apex:page controller="HeddyLoginController">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock title="Login to Heddy">
            <apex:pageMessages/>
            <apex:pageBlockButtons>
                <apex:commandButton value="Search" action="{!login}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageBlockSection>
                <apex:inputfield label="Heddy username" value="{!ps.HeddyUsername__c}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockSection>
                <apex:inputSecret label="Heddy password" value="{!ps.HeddyPassword__c}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

In HeddyLoginController I have code such as this:

```
public class HeddyLoginController {

public String baseEndpoint = 'https://api.Heddy.com/lkapi/'; 
public HeddySession__c ps  { get; set; }

class HeddyAccessException extends Exception {}


public void HeddyLoginController() {
ps = createSession(); 
}

public PageReference login() {
PageReference redirectSuccess = new PageReference('/apex/Search');

if (ps == null) {
    throw new HeddyAccessException('Null error! At the top of login(), ps was null.');
}
HttpResponse response = fetch(ps);
```

I just added that "throw". I am surprised to see it trigger when I submit the form. Perhaps I misunderstood the scope of variables.

Why is ps null in login()?

And the createSession function looks like this:

```
    public HeddySession__c createSession() {
        HeddySession__c HeddySession = new HeddySession__c();

        try {
            insert HeddySession;
        } catch(System.DMLException e) {
            ApexPages.addMessages(e);
            ApexPages.Message msgErr = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Error! We are unable to save your session in Salesforce.');
            ApexPages.addmessage(msgErr);
        }

        return HeddySession;
    }
```

Comment: Turn on Developer mode in your user profile, it will tell you exactly what you're de-referencing..

Comment: I have developer console open, and I look in the log, but it only tells me what I already knew: the error is on line 84, which is the line I posted above.

Comment: Made some changes, now I get: "
Could not resolve the entity from <apex:inputField> value binding '{!ps.HeddyUsername__c}'. <apex:inputField> can only be used with SObjects, or objects that are Visualforce field component resolvable."

Comment: Okay, I just updated this with new tests that I added to my code.

Comment: "ps" is null at the top of the login() function, so perhaps I misunderstood the scope of class variables in the Apex language. I am new to Apex.

Comment: what's `createSession()`?

Comment: @EricSSH -- I just added the code for createSession()

Comment: Someone else might understand what your trying to do, but take a step back and try this out http://www.rubberduckdebugging.com/, I believe I kind of get what your trying to do.. Are you trying to track logins in a custom object?

Comment: @EricSSH -- I want to get two values from an HTML form. That is all. I'd like people to type in a username and password, and I'd like to get those 2 values in the controller. I am new to Apex, but as near as I can tell, I have to use an sObject, and the 2 inputs in the form need to match 2 custom fields on my custom sObject?

Comment: Well first lets get those 2 fields over into your controller
public String loginName {get; set;}
public String password {get;set;}, then your inputFields would actually populate those 2 fields
I'd actually recommend building a wrapper class that can handle this data

Comment: @EricSSH -- when I started, I put the 2 fields in the controller, but I got a warning saying that the fields needed to belong to an sObject.

Comment: And then I created HeddySession__c as a wrapper class for this data. What are you thinking of when you suggest a wrapper class? In what sense is HeddySession__c not that wrapper class?

Comment: Well, I found out that at least some of the problems I face are due to System.CalloutException: You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to do DML in PageController Constructor. This is common salesforce limitation, DML are not allowed in constructors, you need to insert your instance of HeddySession__c in Action method of the page.

See explanation here:
[Why is DML not allowed in Constructor?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/28833/why-is-dml-not-allowed-in-constructor)

Answer (score 0):

You gave your constructor a return type, so it's considered a regular method, not a constructor.  Visualforce is therefore calling the default constructor, which will not instantiate your variable.  You can change your method to `public HeddyLoginController()` and it should actually get called when the page loads.

Note that due to the way your `createSession()` method is defined, the object will always be instantiated and it will never return `null` - I'm not sure if that is intended or not.  If you would like to to return `null` when the object is not inserted, you could change the definition to (among other possibilities):

```
public HeddySession__c createSession() {
    HeddySession__c HeddySession = new HeddySession__c();

    try {
        insert HeddySession;
    } catch(System.DMLException e) {
        ApexPages.addMessages(e);
        ApexPages.Message msgErr = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Error! We are unable to save your session in Salesforce.');
        ApexPages.addmessage(msgErr);
        HeddySession = null; //Added this line
    }

    return HeddySession;
}
```

On the other hand, it's fairly easy to tell whether or not the object was inserted, if it was not its `ID` field will be `null`.