# How to bypass the allowDml limit in VisualForce Constructor

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am meeting a problem in a community site and cannot find any solution on my own...
We are connecting the community with an external payment system (PayBox) who works like this :

- We redirect the user to the paybox website with some information (payment amount, unique order id ...)
- When the user has finished his payment, he is redirected by paybox to our community site with some information (unique order id, success or not...). This works OK but does not suffice to validate the order in salesforce, the redirection could have been tampered with by the user.
- To be sure the payment was good, Paybox send another request to another url in the community site (a server to server http request - so no javascript) with the same information (unique order id, success or not ...) and some sort of token to be sure this comes from paybox.

I need to memorize the order is valid from this server to server request. I constructed a visualforce page to get the request but i'm blocked by the 'No dml in visualforce constructor' rule.

Does someone have any idea how could i resolve this issue ?
Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is DML not allowed in Constructor?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/28833/why-is-dml-not-allowed-in-constructor)

Comment: @RahulSharma No, I understand the why, executing dml from page call would not be secure in a standard context. But this is not relevant in my context.

Comment: Also i cannot use the solution <apex:page controller="pageController" action="{!doSomeDMLStuff}"> because it uses javascript.

Comment: Just got done posting my answer. What javascript are you talking about? It would help if you edited your question to include your visualforce page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I imagine that you're currently performing the validation in the constructor of your Controller/Extension, and are trying to update a checkbox (or something similar) that tells you whether or not the payment has been validated.

There's no way to perform DML in a Controller/Extension constructor, or in any methods where the call stack involves the constructor.

The answer, then, is to move your DML (at the very least) to a different location. The first idea that comes to my mind would be to make use of the `action` attribute of the `<apex:page>` tag.

I don't believe that the exact behavior of the visualforce rendering process is documented anywhere, but the method specified by the `action` attribute is executed after the constructors for the Controller and all Extensions (if any) are run (but before the page itself is rendered).

Salesforce discourages performing DML in a method that is called via the `action` attribute, but doing so is allowed. If you're worried about doing that, you could abuse a getter method (let's call it `getDoVerify()`) by using visualforce expression syntax to call the method *somewhere* in your page with `{!doVerify}`.

Comment: Hi, This works, thank you ! I was sure that the action was launched from javascript at page load... I was wrong :)

Answer (score -1):

In order to perform DML on page load, you must migrate that method to a static void @RemoteAction method, and use JavaScript Remoting to call it on the page.

Also, use script at the bottom of the page as to make increase the user perceived performance.

```
global with sharing class AccountRemoter {

public String accountName { get; set; }
public static Account account { get; set; }
public AccountRemoter() { } // empty constructor

@RemoteAction
global static Account getAccount(String accountName) {
    account = [SELECT Id, Name, Phone, Type, NumberOfEmployees 
               FROM Account WHERE Name = :accountName];
    return account;
    }
}
```

Sample Page

```
<apex:page controller="AccountRemoter">


<input id="acctSearch" type="text"/>
<button onclick="getRemoteAccount()">Get Account</button>
<div id="responseErrors"></div>

<apex:pageBlock id="block">
    <apex:pageBlockSection id="blockSection" columns="2">
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem id="firstItem">
            <span id="remoteAcctId"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem id="secondItem">
            <apex:outputText id="acctNumEmployees"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

`<script type="text/javascript">`
    `function getRemoteAccount() {
        var accountName = document.getElementById('acctSearch').value;`

```
    Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
        '{!$RemoteAction.AccountRemoter.getAccount}',
        accountName, 
        function(result, event){
            if (event.status) {
                // Get DOM IDs for HTML and Visualforce elements like this
                document.getElementById('remoteAcctId').innerHTML = result.Id
                document.getElementById(
                    "{!$Component.block.blockSection.secondItem.acctNumEmployees}"
                    ).innerHTML = result.NumberOfEmployees;
            } else if (event.type === 'exception') {
                document.getElementById("responseErrors").innerHTML = 
                    event.message;
            } else {
                document.getElementById("responseErrors").innerHTML = event.message;
            }
        }, 
        {escape: true}
    );
}
```

`</script>`

[JavaScript Remoting Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_js_remoting_example.htm)

Comment: I cannot use javascript in this context.