# DML Not Allowed

Tags: apex, visualforce, dml

I am getting an error when trying to kick off an approval flow programatically. I have seen others run into a similar issue with the DML not allowed.

[Why is DML not allowed in Constructor?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/28833/why-is-dml-not-allowed-in-constructor/28853#28853)

I tried to follow a quick easy solution however my debug statement does not fire on my action but it does in the constructor. Is there a way around this. I am really just trying to kick off an approval flow by clicking a button.

Class

```
Public class G_SubmitAllPartsUsedApproval {

    Private Case soMyCase;
    Public  List<Part_Used__c> lstPartsUsed {get; set;} 
    Private boolean doDML;

    Public G_SubmitAllPartsUsedApproval(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) 
    {
        doDML= true;
         system.debug(logginglevel.debug, 'DEBUG: Start G_SubmitAllPartsUsedApproval Constructor' );
         // Get Case ID number 
        This.soMyCase = (Case)stdController.getRecord(); 

        //Get the Case Values for this record
        soMyCase = [Select Id, AccountId, AssetId, CaseNumber, ContactId, PriceBook_Currency_Code__c
                   From Case 
                        Where Id = :This.soMyCase.Id];


        lstPartsUsed = [Select Id
                     From Part_Used__c 
                        Where Case__c = :soMyCase.id];

        system.debug(logginglevel.debug, 'DEBUG: lstPartsUsed is:    '  + lstPartsUsed );



        For (Part_Used__c soPartsUsed : lstPartsUsed){

            SubmitForApproval(soPartsUsed);

        }

    }


    Public Void SubmitForApproval(Part_Used__c PartsUsed)
    {

        system.debug(logginglevel.debug, 'DEBUG: PartsUsed is:    '  + PartsUsed );


        Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest req1 = new Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest();
        req1.setComments('Submitting request for approval automatically using Trigger');
        req1.setObjectId(PartsUsed.id);
        Approval.ProcessResult result = Approval.process(req1);

    }

    public pagereference doSomeDMLStuff(){
        system.debug(logginglevel.debug, 'DEBUG: doDML is:    '  + doDML );
        if(doDML){
         //run DML statements 
    system.debug(logginglevel.debug, 'DEBUG: doDML is:    '  + doDML );
     }
     return null;
     }

}
```

Page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Case" extensions="G_SubmitAllPartsUsedApproval" action="{!doSomeDMLStuff}">
</apex:page>
```

Button 
Javascript

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/31.0/connection.js")} 
window.location = 'apex/G_SubmitAllPartsUsedApproval?id={!Case.Id}';
```

Comment: I'm noticing that your questions still aren't correctly formatting multi-line code. A multi-line code block is formatted by ensuring that every line has at least 4 blank spaces at the start of the line. The easy way to do this (while preserving _all_ of your indentation) is to paste your code, highlight it, and then press `ctrl +k` (`cmd + k` on Mac)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

when you submit a record for approval. It treats as a DML(because of lock and unlock feature) so that you are doing in your constructor.

You can move your approval functionality to `doSomeDMLStuff` method and since `doSomeDMLStuff` called from `apex:page` action attribute. You will not face any issue using this way.

Documentation: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_approval.htm

> Salesforce admins can edit locked records. Depending on your approval
>   process configuration settings, an assigned approver can also edit
>   locked records. Locks and unlocks that are set programmatically use
>   the same record editability settings as other approval-process locks
>   and unlocks.
>
> Record locks and unlocks are treated as DML. They’re blocked before a
>   callout, they count toward your DML limits, and if a failure occurs,
>   they’re rolled back along with the rest of your transaction. To change
>   this rollback behavior, use an allOrNone parameter.
>
> Approval is also used as a namespace for the ProcessRequest and
>   ProcessResult classes.